# how to pad zeros into file contents?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

trying to pad 34/0/2 for two digits to 34/0/02.
my code.
suggestions....?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F  "tokens=1,2,3,4,5* delims=,/" %%a IN (temp1.csv) do (
    echo orig %%a/%%b/%%c,%%d,%%e 
    echo new %%a/%%b/%c:~-2%,%%d,%%e  >>  temp3.csv
)
type temp3.csv
```

temp1.csv  file contents

```
Gi-34/0/1,lpu,w-3-016ch1swA1p19_lag   
Gi-34/0/10,lpu,w-3-018ch1swA2p19_lag   
Gi-34/0/11,lpu,prodca1_lan_sec   
Gi-34/0/12,lpu,prodca2_lan_sec   
Gi-34/0/13,lpd,   
Gi-34/0/14,lpd,   
Gi-34/0/15,lpd,   
Gi-34/0/16,lpd,   
Gi-34/0/17,lpd,   
Gi-34/0/18,lpu,aix_to_hmc   
Gi-34/0/19,lpu,prodcafl1_lan_sec   
Gi-34/0/2,lpu,w-3-016ch1swA2p19_lag   
Gi-34/0/20,lpu,prodcafl2_lan_sec
```

Comment: You have to assign %%c to an environmental variable first.  When doing that add a zero to the front then pull the last two positions when you output the variable.  You will need to use delayed expansion.

Comment: There are 2 errors: 1. the sub-string expansion syntax cannot be used on `for` references, so you need to assign its value to a normal environment variable first; when doing so, take a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)! 2. extracting a sub-string from a one-digit number does not create an additional zero, so you will have to add the leading zero in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to add the current content to 100 and take the last two digits.
You referenced a var `%c%` which didn't exist. To better distinguish I use an uppercase var `!C!` with delayed expansion. There are only 3 vars and the rest so it's `tokens=1-3*`.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
Type Nul >temp3.csv
FOR /F  "tokens=1-3* delims=,/" %%a IN (temp1.csv) do (
    echo orig %%a/%%b/%%c,%%d
    Set /A C=100 + %%c
    echo new %%a/%%b/!C:~-2!,%%d  >>  temp3.csv
)
type temp3.csv
```

Sample output:

```
new Gi-34/0/01,lpu,w-3-016ch1swA1p19_lag
new Gi-34/0/10,lpu,w-3-018ch1swA2p19_lag
new Gi-34/0/11,lpu,prodca1_lan_sec
new Gi-34/0/12,lpu,prodca2_lan_sec
new Gi-34/0/13,lpd,
new Gi-34/0/14,lpd,
new Gi-34/0/15,lpd,
new Gi-34/0/16,lpd,
new Gi-34/0/17,lpd,
new Gi-34/0/18,lpu,aix_to_hmc
new Gi-34/0/19,lpu,prodcafl1_lan_sec
new Gi-34/0/02,lpu,w-3-016ch1swA2p19_lag
new Gi-34/0/20,lpu,prodcafl2_lan_sec
```